# I'm trying custom bottom navigation

Tags: android, user-interface

I want to design bottom layout like in the picture but I unable to do that now.[I'm getting this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78Inx.png)  I tried many code. but 
[I need this curve in bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2WR5.png)

I need exactly like in this picture.
Bottom navigation bar working fine. but layout look so bad

Below my code

```
// get width and height of navigation bar
    // Navigation bar bounds (width & height)
    mNavigationBarWidth = getWidth();
    mNavigationBarHeight = getHeight();
    // the coordinates (x,y) of the start point before curve
    mFirstCurveStartPoint.set((mNavigationBarWidth / 2) - (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2) - (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 3), 0);
    // the coordinates (x,y) of the end point after curve
    mFirstCurveEndPoint.set(mNavigationBarWidth / 2, CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 4));
    // same thing for the second curve
    mSecondCurveStartPoint = mFirstCurveEndPoint;
    mSecondCurveEndPoint.set((mNavigationBarWidth / 2) + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2) + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 3), 0);

    // the coordinates (x,y)  of the 1st control point on a cubic curve
    mFirstCurveControlPoint1.set(mFirstCurveStartPoint.x + CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 4), mFirstCurveStartPoint.y);
    // the coordinates (x,y)  of the 2nd control point on a cubic curve
    mFirstCurveControlPoint2.set(mFirstCurveEndPoint.x - (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2) + CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS, mFirstCurveEndPoint.y);

    mSecondCurveControlPoint1.set(mSecondCurveStartPoint.x + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2) - CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS, mSecondCurveStartPoint.y);
    mSecondCurveControlPoint2.set(mSecondCurveEndPoint.x - (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 4)), mSecondCurveEndPoint.y);

    mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo(0, 0);
    mPath.lineTo(mFirstCurveStartPoint.x, mFirstCurveStartPoint.y);

    mPath.cubicTo(mFirstCurveControlPoint1.x, mFirstCurveControlPoint1.y,
            mFirstCurveControlPoint2.x, mFirstCurveControlPoint2.y,
            mFirstCurveEndPoint.x, mFirstCurveEndPoint.y);

    mPath.cubicTo(mSecondCurveControlPoint1.x, mSecondCurveControlPoint1.y,
            mSecondCurveControlPoint2.x, mSecondCurveControlPoint2.y,
            mSecondCurveEndPoint.x, mSecondCurveEndPoint.y);

    mPath.lineTo(mNavigationBarWidth, 0);
    mPath.lineTo(mNavigationBarWidth, mNavigationBarHeight);
    mPath.lineTo(0, mNavigationBarHeight);
    mPath.close();
```